# How to exclude a transitive dependency in Gradle regardless of depth?

Tags: gradle

I have a dependency (`com.conflict:conflicting-dependency:1.2`) in a Gradle build file which is coming from a transitive dependency (`org.foo:bar:1.0`) that is nested several layers deep.

```
org.foo:bar:1.0
| - com.nested:nested1:5.5.1
|    | - com.nested:nested2:3.3.1
|    |    - com.conflict:conflicting-dependency:1.2
```

What is the correct way to exclude this dependency?

I know I can just define `com.conflict:conflicting-dependency:2.5` as an explicit dependency of the project, but is this the only way and is it the correct way?

I am askinig, because the dependency graph that this relates to is actually massively more complicated and I'd like to clean up the dependency mess that we seem to have. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
implementation ("org.foo:bar:1.0") {
    exclude group: 'com.conflict', module: 'conflicting-dependency'
}
```